# Can I repair this lithium battery pack

Tags: battery

I carelessly left a worklight outside in a tarp, and was unfortunate enough that it rained. I appear to have drowned my 5.0AH Ryobi Battery pack...

I have average soldering skills, so I am not averse to sourcing and soldering new parts on, but I am worried about the corrosion around the two lithium cells. I am not sure that I can replace those two with the equipment I have, therefore I am writing this post to strangers on the internet, hoping that they have the experience I lack to judge this situation.

[image: Battery condition]

Comment: Seeing all the bad press that new/in good condition rechargeable batteries get, it might not be worth it.

Comment: @crip659 I agree, I would not trust this pack after repair. Recycle it. This has nothing to do with the FUD that the press loads up about batteries. They're quite safe in general. This is a silly risk to take though IMO.

Comment: @KMJ lithiums *are* dangerous as heck. The only thing that keeps them safe is very good battery management.  Think of it as akin to deep sea diving... safe only because of obsessive attention to every safety detail.  **This is not the same thing as "safe" and it may still be brutally unforgiving to the careless.**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about electronics repair and not home improvement.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I'm familiar, I've built packs. They can absolutely cause a huge mess. It's why I wouldn't recommend repairing this pack: you don't know what has happened to these poor cells. What I take issue with is pointing to the bad press, because the press blows the overall risk way out of proportion. If you're following the directions using full devices and batteries, it's going to be incredibly rare for an individual user to have an issue with a lithium pack.

Answer (score 1):

I've got nearly 40 years experience as an electronics tech. IMHO I'd check the cost of that transistor. If the cells aren't corroded internally, and they aren't otherwise obviously damaged, it's worth a shot. It looks to me like that transistor ended up shorted.

Issues with LION batteries are relatively rare... they are generally caused by shorted cells themselves, not shorted components in the pack.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to ask, I have to say "no".

Lithium batteries contain a huge amount of energy for their size. That's why they're used. But it also means that if you get charging wrong they can start fires or explode, and even pros have sometimes gotten that wrong (websearch "exploding burning laptop battery" for some articles and videos).

So repairing a damaged lithium battery pack is somewhat fraught. Not a project I'd favor.

Replacing worn-out cells in an *intact* battery pack with truly identical cells, maybe.